# Where is the fault in the above code?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, drupal-7

```
$status = db_insert('errors', 'e')
      ->fields('e', array('status' => 'correct',))
      ->execute();
```

Why these lines of code do not insert values in the status column??

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$status = db_insert('errors')
->fields(array(
  'status' => 'correct'
))
->execute();
```

Comment: Would you please explain your answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @VicAbreu I do not think there is much to explain :-) It is just the correction in the wrong syntax.

Comment: As for explanation: the original code was trying to conform to `SelectQuery::fields()` instead of `DeleteQuery::fields()`. The arguments are different